# Laravel 10 Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validatePhone does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-10

I'm trying to make an Auth API with Laravel 10. In the API I want a user to sign up with the email or phone number but when login in, I want only to use the phone number.

So, I used this method in the registration and login form but when I test it in postman, I get this error:

> Error "BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validatePhone does not exist."

##### API Controller

```
// Register API (POST, formdata)
public function register(Request $request){

    // data validation
    $request->validate([
        "name" => "required",
        "email" => "email|unique:users",
        "phone" => "required|phone:ML",
        "password" => "required|confirmed"
    ]);

    // Author model
    User::create([
        "name" => $request->name,
        "email" => $request->email,
        "phone" => $request->phone,
        "password" => Hash::make($request->password)
    ]);

    // Response
    return response()->json([
        "status" => true,
        "message" => "User created successfully"
    ]);
}

// Login API (POST, formdata)
public function login(Request $request){

    // Data validation
    $request->validate([
        //"email" => "required|email",
        "phone" => "required|phone:ML",
        "password" => "required"
    ]);

    // Auth Facade
    if(Auth::attempt([
        //"email" => $request->email,
        "phone" => $request->phone,
        "password" => $request->password
    ])){

        $user = Auth::user();

        $token = $user->createToken("myToken")->accessToken;

        return response()->json([
            "status" => true,
            "message" => "Login successful",
            "access_token" => $token
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Invalid credentials"
    ]);
}
```

Comment: [Phone is not one of the available validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#available-validation-rules). Did you try [creating it yourself?](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: Are you following some documentation for the syntax `phone:ML`? I checked through all versions of Laravel's validation documentation, and none of them mention a `phone` rule (I was curious if it was deprecated from an earlier version, but I also see you're using `laravel-10`, so ‍♂️)

Comment: I was following a forum post for phone validation they use this

$request->validate([ // Allow only phone numbers from the FR 'phone_number' => 'required|phone:FR', ]);

so i tryed to integrate it with Mali code witch's ML

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed the composer package. As per the question, if you need to use a `phone` validation, you must use this.

```
composer require propaganistas/laravel-phone
```

**[Propaganistas / Laravel-Phone](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone)**

> I'm not sure county `ML` is available. But you can check the doc

---

By default, `phone` validation isn't available in [vailable Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#available-validation-rules).

Answer (score -1):

```
  $request->validate([
        //"email" => "required|email",
        "phone" => "required|phone:ML",
        "password" => "required"
    ]);
```

That phone is not a valid rule for laravel, for validate the phone use regex expression.

```
'phone' => ['required', 'numeric', 'regex:/^[0-9]{10}$/',]
```

Comment: Please let me know if i am wrong or is there any better approach available.

Comment: Ok, thnk to you. I'll try it and give u a feedback

Comment: This Method doesn't work ither

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @MrSahel "so i tryed to integrate it with Mali code witch's ML", what do you mean by that can you explain in details what you want to achieve, that will may help to identify the issue.

Comment: thnks to all of you,  "so i tryed to integrate it with Mali code witch's ML" i mean by this sentence that the MALI country phone code is (ML), i tryed to reproduct this code (  $request->validate([ 'phone_number' => 'required|phone:FR', ]); in this you can si FR for France phone Code.

Comment: i already put all i know about this subject, right now i dont realy know what to do, if you have methode for phone validation in Laravel API Rest, explain me please.